# PasswordHash not working with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, password-hash

I have put the files I downloaded from http://www.openwall.com/phpass/ to `application/libraries`

In my controller, I am using this code -

```
$params = array(
       'phpass_hash_strength' => 8,
           'phpass_hash_portable' => FALSE
       );
$this->load->library('PasswordHash', $params);
$password = $this->passwordhash->HashPassword($pwd);
```

I am getting these errors -

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Uninitialized string offset: 3

Filename: libraries/PasswordHash.php

Line Number: 116
```

---

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: strpos() [function.strpos]: Empty delimiter

Filename: libraries/PasswordHash.php

Line Number: 116
```

### Update

Removed `PasswordHash.php`, using **SimpleLoginSecure** now.

Comment: Which OS are you using? Which crypts are installed within you PHP installation?

Comment: @hakre I am running win 7 ... crypts, i guess the ones which come with php 5.3.4

Comment: Just had the same problem, you probably needed to rename the constructor to `__construct()` to work in later PHP versions.

Comment: @Xeoncross ,Great.I am using ubuntu 16,php-7 & CI3 it works for me.Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is you are trying to use a generic PHP object as a CodeIgniter library.  You can't just do that.  You'll need to modify the original code to work, or download one of the [contributed libraries already designed for CodeIgniter](http://download.openwall.net/pub/projects/phpass/contrib/codeigniter/).

CodeIgniter libraries have some restrictions (such as how they are instantiated), so just dropping any file into the libraries folder won't work.

Comment: I have modified the PasswordHash.php to make it like a library file. It is loading the library, but the function is not working.

Comment: Well, it looks like you've broken the function.  Look at line 116 in your modified class.  What is going on there?  There's a lot of information in the error output, but only if someone has access to the source.  If you've modified it, it would be difficult for us to reproduce.

Comment: I have not modified the whole class, I just changed it's name. That can't make this big a difference.

Comment: If you just changed the name, then you didn't modify the class to work with CodeIgniter.  Look at [Passing Parameters when Initializing Your Class in the CodeIgniter manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html).  The original class accepts two arguments.

Comment: I chucked the old class. Making db changes according to `SimpleLoginSecure.php` now

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue whilst integrating PasswordHash into Symfony2.

To solve it, I renamed the `PasswordHash` method to `__construct`.

In theory, PHP 5+ should look for a method with the same name as the class if it can't find a constructor (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php). My guess is that the class name resolves differently once a namespace is added (a requirement for my integration), but I've not investigated at all.

Comment: This solved my issue when converting a regular PHP project to use Composer and moving PHPass into a namespace. Checking passwords seemed to work fine, but hashing them did not.

Comment: This worked. After changing the namespace, I had the same issue as @wwarren, but following your approach, it was fixed. Thanks!

Comment: This should be the answer. The class is based on PHP4, so there is no construct method.